# CentOS Python multiple interpreters issue - incorrect shebang

Tags: python, cron, interpreter

I'm trying to run a Python script (testing.py) as a cron job. I have CentOS with a separate python2.7 interpreter path, so I've added the following shebang:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

However, when the cron job runs I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/carsales/carsales_v2.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I have installed Anaconda, and if I run the python2.7 interpreter through the command line, as:

```
python2.7 testing.py
```

It imports pandas successfully. However, running it directly (as per below) fails to import:

```
./testing.py
```

So there's some problem with the shebang, or possibly with the Anaconda install?

Comment: What is the output of `which python2.7` from the root shell?

Comment: /root/anaconda2/bin/python2.7

Comment: Well then, that's your solution right there. Simply change the first line to point to Anaconda's version of python, and your script that requires pandas will work.